# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted but already allocated 1.75G

Tags: php, memory, composer-php, out-of-memory

I keep getting this memory error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in 
phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/
   DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220
```

I have tried everything. Increased the memory limit a few times already. I've redownloaded composer and composer.phar. I cloned my repo on a fresh install and the first `composer install` worked. For some reason every attempt after causes this error.

I even removed any differences in files from the master branch and my branch that could be causing this.

PhP version 7.1.25
Composer version 1.7.2

Code I edited in a config.yml file

```
create_course_space_whitelist_expression: '"staff" in affiliations or 
"employee" in affiliations or "faculty" in affiliations or "guest" in 
affiliations or "GR" in student_level'
```

old code:

```
create_course_space_whitelist_expression: '"staff" in affiliations or 
"employee" in affiliations or "faculty" in affiliations or "guest" in 
affiliations
```

Not sure where else to look. I updated two created files within Vendor but I'm deleting vendor before running `composer install`

EDIT:

I've been able to narrow down the cause. `composer install` works fine the when working with a clean version of the repo branch. However, when any change is made to the composer.json file, it fails

Comment: We also need to see the code you are executing that results in this error, you could have problems with your code, such as an infinite loop, etc.

Comment: How do I know which code is producing this error?

Comment: You don't. That's why I'm asking to post the code that is being run for this page. (Example: your controller, any function, etc).

Comment: @Jonathan I got the impression they were getting this error when they ran composer install, not necessarily from code they wrote

Comment: Totally my bad, you are right @Don'tPanic

Comment: @Don'tPanic is correct, but I did edit in response

Comment: Does your repo include a composer.lock file? And do the subsequent composer install attempts always fail, or only after you make that edit you showed?

Comment: I added a composer tag to your question. Honestly I'm probably not enough of a composer expert to solve the problem, but hopefully someone who watches that tag could help you.

Comment: I've updated my issue which hopefully can narrow it down

Comment: update you composer version to 2

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Running this command fixed it for me

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

Comment: what about windows?  i use windows 10 and this command worked for me, php -d memory_limit=-1 "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update

Comment: According to @sabertabatabaeeyazdi  comment
`php -d memory_limit=-1 "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update` will work for windows

Answer (score 19):

In my case with Xampp with Windows 10

i just changed:

```
;memory_limit=512M
```

by commenting this configuration, in php.ini to:

```
memory_limit =-1
```

then restart the Apache by xampp

[image]

Comment: this works on windows 10 with xampp server, thank you

Comment: happy to help 1.4 millions of people that stackexchange estimates in  my profile 2.4 million !!! im sorry 2.4 is correct @MohamedRaza

Answer (score 15):

Update Composer to version 2 and it will resolve this issue automatically.

```
composer self-update --2
```

**Note** : argument `--2` is optional. it will upgrade the current composer version to 2 only. Without it, the composer will update to the latest version (it's the same version 2 currently but in future, it may be 3)

Comment: That solved the problem on Windows 10 with xampp installed. Do you have any idea what was this about? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Mycodingproject : Thanks for the comment. Honestly, I don't have much idea but it seems there is a bug on Composer causing the memory to be exhausted by run `composer install` or `composer update`.

Comment: Only used `composer self-update` to update to the latest version of composer

Comment: Using MAMP 6.6.4 on macOS Monterey, and this worked for me. Just run `composer self-update` without any other parameters.

Answer (score 7):

what about windows?

i use windows 10 and this command worked for me,

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update
```

Answer (score 5):

Run `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install` instead of `composer install`

Answer (score 4):

in WINDOWS you can use this:

```
set COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
```

in windows 10 and with terminal and laragon it worked for me

Comment: This worked for me as well using Laragon on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update

try this it's working for me